# ExtJs validation grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

I should do validation for editable grid. I use `Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing` to edit a grid.

To edit a grid I overrode `initComponent` in `Ext.Editor` and set `msgTarget 'side'`. It works good.

But I cannot see error picture in any cell, not only editable.

```
_______________________________________
|_not_valid_____@|______________|_____|
|________________|__not_valid__@|_____|
|_not_valid_____@|______________|_____|
```

Where @ errorEl, when we direct it an error message appears.

How can I insert error message in any cell?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question or add a sample of your issue to [http://jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Hmm, what's the `CellEditing` plugin? Have you described fields correctly (e.g. `allowBlank: false`)?